# Phaser 3 interactive hitarea of a container

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a container containing an image and some text;
We are facing an issue with the interactive hitarea of the container

```
this.image = this.add.image(0, 0, 'GreenButtonBox').setOrigin(0.5).setScale(2);
this.text = this.add.text(0, 0, "Click", { font: "bold 35px Arial", fill: '#ffffff' }).setOrigin(0.5).setScale(1);
this.container = this.add.container(400, 400, [this.image, this.text])
    .setSize(this.image.width, this.image.height)
    .setInteractive()
    .on('pointerup', this.SubmitAnswer);
```

In the case above the interactive part of the button is located in the middle (maybe due to the scale of the image?

I also tried adding `new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle` to the interactive function as such

`.setInteractive(new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height), Phaser.Geom.Rectangle.Contains)`

but the clickable area become the lower right corner of the button; wheras with

`.setInteractive(new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle((this.image.width / 2) * -1, (this.image.height / 2) * -1, this.image.width, this.image.height), Phaser.Geom.Rectangle.Contains)`

the clickable area becomes the uper left part of the button;

Do I need to account for the scale myself? such as

`.setInteractive(new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle((this.image.width / 2) * -1, (this.image.height / 2) * -1, this.image.width * 2, this.image.height * 2), Phaser.Geom.Rectangle.Contains)`

**This actually works**

I'm confused as to why I need to scale the image again when I'm taking the image width and height for the container width and height.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `height` and `width` won't work *(they hold the original size)*, but you could simply use the properties `displayWidth` and `displayHeight`, this properties gives you the right size *(especially after scaling)*, calculation is handled by phaser.

**Here a small demo illustrating this:**

```js
let Scene = {
      preload(){
        this.load.image('ship', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/ship.png');
      },
      create(){
      
      this.image = this.add.image(0, 0, 'ship').setOrigin(0.5)
          console.info(`before Scale width: ${this.image.width}, height: ${this.image.height}, displayWidth: ${this.image.displayWidth}, displayHeight:${this.image.displayHeight}` );
           this.image.setScale(2);
          console.info(`after Scale width: ${this.image.width}, height: ${this.image.height}, displayWidth: ${this.image.displayWidth}, displayHeight:${this.image.displayHeight}` );
      }
    }
    
    const config = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      width:400,
      height:200,
      scene: Scene,
     banner: false
    }
   const game = new Phaser.Game(config)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```